# I'm getting "clang: error: no input files"

Tags: xcode, clang

I had a file which I deleted and replaced with another file, somewhere else, of the same name.

Despite cleaning, and trying this multiple times, I keep getting this error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Andrew/App/Version 1.1/XCode/UIImage+Alpha.m'
>   clang: error: no input files

I can't continue working on my app because of it. Any ideas?

Comment: when you deleted the file, did you just delete it in Finder, or did you delete the reference to that file in your Xcode project? Check for a leftover reference in the project navigator, or on a target's list of files in the project editor.

Answer (score 103):

The problem might be because your project > target > Build Phases > Compile Sources is trying to compile a file that doesn't exist. It might be in there twice, like the below screen shot. My project contains UIImage+FFXtras, I can even remove it and re-add it and this won't resolve the problem!

[image: missing source file]

I'm not sure how the project gets into this state - but I know it's not obvious what is going wrong. Highlight the red problem one and remove it.

So have a look in compile sources phase for the file clang is complaining about.

Comment: Really obnoxious! This was exactly the problem. Did clean and run; quit Xcode couple of times but did not work.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Pods, for a unknown reason a pod didn't updated and faced the same problem because Xcode search for the library. But with another `pod install` everything works again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Helped me.

Answer (score 6):

Got the similar troubles.

It seems XCode does not generate correct relative filepath when your project refer to an already existing source tree (relative path does not contain the .xcodeproj in the path of the file to be compiled).

There is a simple fix however: in the project explorer select the file or files files then look at the options in the file inspector. One of them is labeled "Location"; set it to absolut path and try again. This fixed the issue for me :)

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem. I had a file that was in the wrong directory!

Comment: when i got this error in Xcode 8 Beta 2, I just closed it and Reopen from folder directory.

Answer (score 4):

Additional to all answers:

1. delete derived data
2. reboot
3. delete derived data
4. clean
5. build
6. Success!

Only this sequence works for me in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I use quite a few cocoa pods and have just had this happen to me.  A quick "pods update" sorted things out for me.  -phil

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vs code and facing this issue which says

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'filename'
clang: error: no input files
```

Error while running files:

[image: error while running files]

I solved this issue by removing the space or replacing the space with *underscore*(_) **in the filename** *.extension*

Answer (score 0):

In case everything fails (i.e. first try bames53 suggestion)

Ok, this might be dangerous **so make a copy of your whole project first**:

- close Xcode
- locate the project file in the Finder
- right click, choose "show package contents"
- open `project.pbxproj` in a text editor of your choice, but not Xcode
- search for your file

  - at the beginning of the line that shows up, you'll see some id like `640450991409CF5C00B3B580`. Search for this and delete any line you find.
  - pay attention, not to break the syntax (balance parenthesis and brackets, pay attention for commas)
- when you are done, save the file and try to open the project in Xcode. Add the missing file via the `Add file…` dialog of Xcode. It is still in the folder of your project — if you added it successfully in the first place — you just got rid of all project references.
- dont be surprised, if it doesnt work instantly — you have a copy. copy it again, new try.

And remember: **make a copy of your whole project first** — for every try. or copying the `project.pbxproj` might be enough.

Comment: I think this happens when you try to pull merge from git and try to resolve conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your pod-file and run pod install:

```
use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in monodevelop. I just went to edit>preferences
and changed the default location of the program files. It was set to the monodevelop default they give you when you open a file and not the folder i changed it too.
Likely, you need to adjust the settings of xcode, where you stored your files.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this while setting up a React Native project.  Solved it using:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

[Source](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2290)