# iOS archive with error linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

When I run my app on my `iPhone simulator`, I get no errors and it runs. Yet, when I attempt to archive my app it gives me the `error`

> ```
> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I read other posts on this and tried changing the architecture to `armv7` only (rather than also `armv7s`) but that did not work either. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: check in your source code if any file or image is missing?, if not then try to restart xcode sometimes its works for me in same condition

Comment: [One of the case.. Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12218432/1059705)