# xcode 6: Apple mach-o linker error; linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode6, archive

i am trying to create a archive of my ios project which created using xcode 6. it is working fine in my stimulater but when i try to create an archive of this it gives me this error.

> ld: library not found for -lobjc clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

when i googled the error it given me the below post. but it didn't had any effective solution given. and they done a better work in explain this problem.. so please look into this post if you can't understand what i am saying. please help.

thanks in advance.

[iOS archive with error linker command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706871/ios-archive-with-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)

[Linker command failed with exit code 1; undefined symbols for architecture armv7s.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583690/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: Does your Xcode project run properly in iOS simulator and Device?