# SDWebImage Apple LLVM 6.0 Error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, semantics, sdwebimage, xcode6.1

I am new for iOS development

LLVM related issue already posted on stackoverflow but I thought it is new with SDWebImage, Or If I am wrong please suggest on that.

I want to make tableview with async image loading.
As per my R&D SDWebImage is best. 
For that, I downloaded SDWebImage project from GitHub
[link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
and framework 3.7.1 from [link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases)

I am using Xcode 6.1.1

But I am getting Apple LLVM 6.0 Error, How can i resolve it. Please help me.

[image]

[EDITED] I removed framework and added same again. This time I saw the old issue resolved and getting new 2 issues

1. Semantic issue
2. ARC Semantic issue

Please check following screen shot

[image: 2]

Comment: When you import the SDWebImage files, make sure you check the "Copy files..." box at the top of the dialog so they aren't trying to be built out of your Downloads folder. Also, rather than manual integration you could try CocoaPods or Carthage (if SDWebImage supports it).

Comment: the file Name **random.c** is missing, so delete and add your file again once, surely works

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm getting "clang: error: no input files"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352507/im-getting-clang-error-no-input-files)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:-

1- Clear Drived data.
 2- Remove reference of your class and then again Add that file.
3- Clean the product.
4- Quite your Xcode.
5 - Then run and check.
 Hope this will be helpful to resolve the problem.

Comment: I tried little bit same but not success yet, Now I am getting semantic and ARC issue with same, Please check edited text and new screen shot ones.

Comment: Are you enable Arc for that third party SDWebImage. and go on that class of SDWebImage and check, is there property USerName and Password are exist or not